# Relative clauses with used

Tags: relative-clauses

Which one is correct and why?

> The method used in this research was terrible.
>
> The method which used in this research was terrible.
>
> The method which is used in this research was terrible.

And about the first one: why 'which' has been left out? To my understanding we cannot omit 'which' where it's a subject of the relative clause.

Comment: Exam questions may be off topic.

Comment: **The method was terrible.** Which method? **The method (which was) used in the research.**  The past tense is needed as the research is presumably finished. Leaving out 'which was' shortens the sentence and  doesn't make the meaning any less clear.

Comment: On the relative clause grammar, it might help to think of 'the method used' as 'the method which one used' which makes method the object rather than subject of the relative clause.

Comment: You may want to do a search for “whiz-deletion”. There are other questions about this topic on this site: https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/whiz-deletion?sort=votes&pageSize=30

Answer (score 0):

As a matter of fact the first example is not a relative clause at all. So nothing had been omitted in the first place.

As 'English grammar in use' says(page 194), it is a '-ed clause'.
The word 'Used' is a past participle not past and it has a passive meaning.